# How to remove a SVN basepath from my c:\ drive?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

So here's what I did.

I installed TortoiseSVN client and used its Check Out option to check code out from the server repository. However it asked me what should be the basepath for that repository on my c: drive and instead of allowing it to create the default folder in the root I assumed that this folder is part of the actual check out and I pointed Tortoise to the c:\

Obviously this was not correct and now I have a c:\ drive marked as out of sync with the repository and there seem to be no option to unmount/remove that repository basepath from c:\

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is, through Windows Explorer and the ToirtoiseSVN options, Export your repository ***to the same location*** (i.e. C:\ in your case).

```
TortoiseSVN -> Export
```

This will remove the .svn folders and it will no longer be a working copy. The svn icons on your files and folders will update and go away shortly afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete all of the folders in C:\ that were created via the checkout.  Then delete the .svn folder in the root of C:\ and it will no longer be considered an SVN working copy.